# symmetric boundary condition for 1d convolution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution, boundary

Let `h_0_2 = np.array([0.0625, 0.,     0.25,   0.,     0.375,  0.,     0.25,   0.,     0.0625])`. In the 2D scenario I can specify the desired boundary with `scipy.signal.convolve2d` which is in my case the symmetrical boundary conditions. I haven't found the same option for 1D so I think I have to add the boundary condition 'manually'. To my understanding this can be basically achieved by adding a Hankel-matrix to `np.convolve(h_0_2, v, 'same')` where `v` is the array with which we want to convolve.
Any idea how this would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`convolve1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve1d.html) that lets you specify all sorts of things including boundary conditions in the `scipy.ndimage` module.